# ERROR HY000 (1105): unknown: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = last resolver error: produced zero addresses when attempting to query PlanetScale DB

Tags: database, prisma, planetscale

I'm getting an `Error: Error in connector: Error querying the database: Error querying the database: Error querying the database: Server error: ERROR HY000 (1105): unknown: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = last resolver error: produced zero addresses'` error message when one of my NextJS API routes tries querying my PlanetScale DB. This error message bubbles up into my browser's network tab. This is in my local environment, but my production deployment is working fine. I'm also seeing this when using `npx prisma db pull`.

Answer (score 0):

It's probable that one of the passwords were discarded via the PlanetScale dashboard, and that just means that a new password must be created and used locally. One way to do this is to click on the `Connect` button while viewing the DB's dashboard page and clicking the `New password` button to generate a new one.

Comment: This did not do the trick for me. I am unsure how this error would relate to this issue? I can use the other credentials to read a few rows. The issue seems rather to be when getting the complete table, with something like datagrip